# gnus doesn't periodically check emails

Tags: gnus, email

I have the following in my ~/.gnus:

```
(gnus-demon-add-handler, 'gnus-demon-scan-mail 5 t)
(gnus-demon-init)
```

I expect that gnus will be checking for new emails every 5 min, however this doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should remove the `comma` after `gnus-demon-add-handler`

Comment: Have you tried `gnus-demon-scan-news` instead of `gnus-demon-scan-mail`? At first glance the latter does not seem to cover all backends, e.g. nnimap, which is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `nnmaildir` or `nnml`?  It seems to me that the daemon does not work for `nnmaildir`. Can someone confirm please.

Here is the code for gnus-demon-scan-mail

```
(defun gnus-demon-scan-mail ()
  (save-window-excursion
(let ((servers gnus-opened-servers)
  server
  (nnmail-fetched-sources (list t)))
  (while (setq server (car (pop servers)))
(and (gnus-check-backend-function 'request-scan (car server))
     (or (gnus-server-opened server)
     (gnus-open-server server))
     (gnus-request-scan nil server))))))
```

*Edit*
I have found these two functions on the gnus mailing list. They are really helpful to understand how things work.

```
;;; * check new mail
;;; ** function def
(defun gnus-demon-scan-mail-or-news-and-update (level)
"Scan for new mail, updating the *Group* buffer."
  (let ((win (current-window-configuration)))
    (unwind-protect
        (save-window-excursion
          (save-excursion
            (when (gnus-alive-p)
              (save-excursion
                (set-buffer gnus-group-buffer)
                (gnus-group-get-new-news level)))))
      (message "scanning for new mail done")
      (set-window-configuration win))))

(defun gnus-demon-scan-news-and-update ()
"Scan for new mail, updating the *Group* buffer."
  (gnus-demon-scan-mail-or-news-and-update 3))

;;; ** command
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-news-and-update 10 nil)
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-demon-scan-mail 10 nil)
(gnus-demon-init)
```

And I'm using `nnml` as my mail back-end with `procmail` and `fetchmail`

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnml ""))
(setq mail-sources  '((file :path "~/.mail/inbox.spool")
          ))
```

For mail notification you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611516/2081427
The you get notified in the mode-line each time a mail new mail comes.

**Note** I couldn't make `gnus-notify.el` work for more than one group. So as far as I know
if you use nnmail-split-methods and want `gnus-notify.el` for more than one group it won't work.

Comment: I use multiple `nnimap` backends as `gnus-secondary-select-methods` with no `gnus-select-metho` and `gnus-demon-scan-mail` does not work OOTB for me. Instead, I rescan for mail with `gnus-demon-scan-news`.

Comment: Thanks for the feed-back. I've updated my post wiht my current knowledge on the matter. cheers

Comment: Just to be clear - `gnus-demon-scan-news` and `gnus-demon-scan-mail` are built-in functions of `gnus-demon.el`. Also the built-in `gnus-notify.el` is a different package than the third-party `gnus-desktop-notify.el` package which you linked.

Comment: Apologies, I mixed up the third-party `gnus-notify.el` with the built-in `gnus-notifications.el`, which you may be interested in.